# How to Convert UTM to Lat/Lng ? GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_55/GEOGCS["GCS_GDA_1994

Tags: java, android, gis

```
I have no idea about coordinate systems. How can I convert UTM to Lat/Lng ?

PROJCS["GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_55", 
  GEOGCS["GCS_GDA_1994", 
    DATUM["D_GDA_1994", 
      SPHEROID["GRS_1980", 6378137.0, 298.257222101]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Latitude", NORTH]], 
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 147.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 10000000.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["x", EAST], 
  AXIS["y", NORTH]]

MULTIPOLYGON (((537325.7973699234 6112549.51248766, 537329.647362587 6112573.895774531, 537321.690711082 6112575.9491039505, 537323.2307081465 6112588.269080476, 537331.9573581843 6112586.72908341, 537333.2406890718 6112593.402404027, 537345.5606655972 6112591.349074606, 537339.1440111566 6112547.202492061, 537325.7973699234 6112549.51248766)))
```

Using Geotools I am able to read a shapefile and above is my output. Now I have to show polygon on Google map and OSM map, But unable to convert these points to Geocoordinate.